# Not sure why do I get an error when doing k-Fold Cross validation

Tags: python-3.x, keras, k-fold

I'm learning neural networks and I copied a code example but I'm not sure why do I get an error.
Here is my code

```
df = pd.read_csv('games.csv')
df =df.dropna()
X = df[['Goals', 'Saves', 'Wins', 'Games']]
Y = df['Shots']
seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)
# define 10-fold cross validation test harness
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
cvscores = []
for train, test in kfold.split(X, Y):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(16, input_dim=4, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    # Fit the model
    model.fit(X[train], Y[train], epochs=150, batch_size=10, verbose=0)
    # evaluate the model
    scores = model.evaluate(X[test], Y[test], verbose=0)
    print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
    cvscores.append(scores[1] * 100)
print("%.2f%% (+/- %.2f%%)" % (numpy.mean(cvscores), numpy.std(cvscores)))
```

The error I get is

```
raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([   1,    2,    3,    4,    5,    6,    7,    8,    9,   10,\n            ...\n            3088, 3089, 3090, 3091, 3092, 3093, 3094, 3095, 3096, 3097],\n           dtype='int64', length=2788)] are in the [columns]"
```

Example of X because df is too big with over a hundred columns

Saves                  Games                       Wins                        Goals
82.60                     0.765                       0.51140                     0.5492
86.40                    0.56100                     0.4902                       0.71860
75.60                    0.45620                     0.5152                       0.87820
87.00                    0.52400                     0.5266                       0.63940
82.40                    0.51180                     0.5176                      0.74600
80.80                    0.50380                     0.4976                       0.79380
87.00                    0.54580                     0.4934                       0.81160
80.25                    0.46050                     0.5070                      0.72550
88.80                    0.48180                     0.5130                      0.63440
78.20                    0.49500                     0.4920                       0.75160
81.60                    0.50640                     0.4700                       0.77280
80.60                    0.49520                     0.5546                       0.79960
83.60                    0.46060                     0.5070                     0.74940
83.40                    0.45920                     0.4428                        0.75200
84.40                    0.51420                     0.5026                      0.72400
80.40                    0.50260                     0.4554                       0.73640
83.00                    0.49375                     0.4475                       0.74725
79.80                    0.47880                     0.4898                      0.78160

Comment: Can you add a snippet of your dataframe using df.head(20).to_clipboard('',index=True) - Might give a little more insight into the error.

Comment: Added head of X because original df has too many columns

Comment: I wonder if you're getting the error because the X contains floats (numbers with decimals) but the model is looking for int64 (integers without decimals) as noted in the error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with model.fit(X[train], Y[train] where it had to be model.fit(X.iloc[train], Y.iloc[train]